ModuleNotFoundError while running speech_recognition
Below is problem that I am facing. I am relatively new to python and I am working on an AI project that speaks and takes audio. I am using library pyttsx3 and Speech_recognition. Here I have installed Speech_recognition library it installed perfectly and while writting code and running this problem show ups. What should I do? The library pyttsx3 is running perfectly. But I am facing problem with Second one. This is the problem:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Projects\Finer Project\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    takecommand()

  File "e:\Projects\Finer Project\main.py", line 28, in takecommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
  File "E:\pt\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
  File "E:\pt\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'


I was expecting that it should take what I say and respond according to that call. I have installed pyttsx3 for audio it's running perfectly. But my speechrecognition library is not able to recognize voices what should i do?


Hi, distutils package is only available for python<=3.11. You will need to install older python versions to run the library

please fix this, if you're showing an error then wrap it with ``` at the start and at the end

distutils is deprecated, and can only be used on python <= 3.11, but you can install setup tools, which does the same thing as distutils. and then you can manually edit the package and replace import distutils to import setuptools.dist as distutils.
you can also downgrade python to version 3.11 or bellow
